# Django rest api create email login along with password

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I've created the employee management system using django rest api. I've created the models, views and serializers like shown below. What i need is I've created employee details like his personal details as a register view, but when he login i want to use email and password field as a field to sign with jwt token. How to implement this.

Models.py:

```
Class Employee (models.Model):
 
    Fname = models.charfield()
    Lname = models.charfield()
    Personal _email=models.Emailfield()
    Department= models.choicefield()
    Designation= models.charfield()
```

Serializer.py:

```
Class Employeeserializer(models.Modelserializer):


   class Meta:
        
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__
```

Views.py:

```
Registeremployeeview(createAPIview):

    serializer_class = Employeecreateserializer

    def post(self, request):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                "user": serializer.data,
                "message": "User Created Successfully..!",
            })
```

Now i want to create login view. How to i make email and password login view and serializers without I haven't included that in my models.
Alos i want to login and set authentication with jwt authentication.

Comment: You might want to consider using some of the built in authentication journey's from rest framework. Or describe why they arent suitable and possibly the use case justifying going outside the usual authentication permissions and backends.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me why one or more of the pre-existing authentication mechanisms as described here wouldn't work?

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#tutorial-4-authentication-permissions

Django rest framework supports many out of the box authentication mechanisms, and you can even use custom ones, but you really need to do a bit of reading first to understand the intricacies of each mechanism before deciding which to use, or whether to use a custom one.